# How can i get the selected value in ion-alert radio alert

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

```
async presentAlertRadio(heading:string){
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: heading,
      inputs :[
        {
          name : 'Radio 1',
          type: 'radio',
          label: 'Radio 1',
          value: 'value1',
          checked: true
        },
        {
          name: 'radio2',
          type: 'radio',
          label: 'Radio 2',
          value: 'value2'
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: (data) => {
            console.log('Confirm Ok', data);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

i want to assign the value of the selected radio in my alert controller to a variable, how can i access it.

new to ionic 4 so don't really know

i want to assign my var x = selectedRadio

Answer (score 3):

```
      text: 'Ok',
              handler: (data) => {
                console.log('Confirm Ok', data); //handle data here eg.
                this.x = data.value1; // this assigns your veritable 'x' to the value 
                                      // of Radio 1
}
```

comment if this needs clarifying

Answer (score 0):

```
text: 'Ok',
              handler: (data) => {
                console.log('Confirm Ok', data); 
                this.x = data; 
}
```

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with an explanation of the code, and why it resolves the original question? That will help future readers understand what's going on, and learn _why_ it works, not just _how_.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a variable where you're going to storage the value. In my example, it's called `selectedAnimal`.

```
async options() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'alertOptions',
      header: 'Choose an animal',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'cat',
          cssClass: 'ion-radio',
          type: 'radio',
          label: 'Cat',
          value: 'Cat',
          handler: () => {
            
          },
          checked: false
        },
        {
          name: 'dog',
          cssClass: 'ion-radio',
          type: 'radio',
          label: 'Dog',
          value: 'Dog',
          handler: () => { 
          }
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          cssClass: 'alert-confirm',
          handler: (data) => {
            console.log('Chosen animal:', data)
            this.selectedAnimal = data;
            if (this.selectedAnimal == undefined) {
              this.toastSelectionError();
            }
            else{
              this.toastConfirm();
            }
            
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
}
```

In the "Ok" button, I handle the values of the radio as `data`, then I give `selectedAnimal` the value of `data`. In addition, I added a conditional to show a toast whether the selection is undefined or if it has value.